# Lynx is stopping loop?

Tags: bash, loops, lynx

I'll just apologize beforehand; this is my first ever post, so I'm sorry if I'm not specific enough, if the question has already been answered and I just didn't look hard enough, and if I use incorrect formatting of some kind.

That said, here is my issue:  In bash, I am **trying to create a script that will read a file** that lists several dozen URL's.  Once it reads each line, I need it to **run a set of actions** on that, the first being to **use lynx to navigate to the website**.  However, in practice, **it will run once perfectly** on the first line.  Lynx goes, the download works, and then the subsequent renaming and organizing of that file go through as well.  But **then it skips all the other lines** and acts like it has finished the whole file.

I have tested to see if it was lynx causing the issue by eliminating all the other parts of the code, and then by just eliminating lynx.  It works without Lynx, but, of course, I need lynx for the rest of the output to be of any use to me.  Let me just post the code:

```
!#/bin/bash

while read line; do
echo $line
  lynx -accept_all_cookies  $line
echo "lynx done"
  od -N 2 -h *.zip | grep "4b50"
echo "od done, if 1 starting..."
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then ls *.*>>logs/zips.log
    else
    od -N 2 -h *.exe | grep "5a4d"
echo "if 2 starting..."     
      if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
      then ls *.*>>logs/exes.log
      else
      od -N 2 -h *.exe | grep "5a4d, 4b50"
echo "if 3 starting..."
        if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]
        then
        ls *.*>>logs/failed.log
        fi
echo "if 3 done"
      fi
echo "if 2 done"
    fi
echo "if 1 done..."
  FILE=`(ls -tr *.* | head -1)`
  NOW=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
echo "vars set"
  mv $FILE "criticalfreepri/${FILE%%.*}(ZCH,$NOW).${FILE#*.}" -u
echo "file moved"
  rm *.zip *.exe
echo "file removed"
done < "lynx"

$SHELL
```

Just to be sure, I do have a file called "lynx" that contains the urls separated by a return each.  Also, I used all those "echo"s to do my own sort of debugging, but I have tried it with and without the echo's.  When I execute the script, the echo's all show up...

Any help is appreciated, and thank you all so much!  Hope I didn't break any rules on this post!

PS:  I'm on Linux Mint running things through the "terminal" program. I'm scripting with bash in Gedit, if any of that info is relevant.  Thanks!

EDIT:  Actually, the echo tests repeat for all three lines.  So it would appear that lynx simply can't start again in the same loop?

**Here is a simplified version of the script, as requested:**

```
!#/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
echo $line
lynx $line
echo "lynx done"
done < "ref/url" 
read "lynx"

$SHELL
```

Note that I have changed the sites the "url" file goes to:

`www.google.com

www.majorgeeks.com

http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/virus-removal-tool.aspx`

Comment: do you really mean to keep testing value of `$?`. recall that `$?` is the return code **from the previously executed command**. I see that you're testing `rc` after `echo`. That will always (well almost always) return `true`. do something like `linx .... ; linx_rc=$? ; if [[ $linx_rc != 0 ]] ; .... `. Also +1 for very good first question, including a reasonable attempt at debugging your problem. Good luck.!

Comment: Ah, I think I see your point.  When I put the echo's in, I was trying to fit them anywhere I could just to see where the code ended, however, as you just pointed out, I suppose that would mess with part of the script!  You're right, thank you for that.  Still, not sure why Lynx would cut out like it does.  Seems like maybe it's not reading the "lynx" file correctly?  (Not the command, the file I confusingly named "lynx".)

Comment: Please edit above to include your best shot and remove descriptions of behavior that are no longer relevant. Feeding file `lynx`  to program `lynx` in a loop seems like a invitation to trouble, so call it (at least) lynx.txt. But to your main question (why is it "hanging"), what is the "target"  in the 2nd line of your input file? Are you hitting a site that is really big, or expecting a password, or a 100 other things that could cause a delay or the perception of a hang? If you run `lynx http://target_from_line_2` from command line, does it work just fine? 
What you have should work. GoodLuck

Comment: Rather than using `echo ....` to debug, remove those and just use the `shell's` natural debugger, by adding `set -x` to turn on display of variable expansions, and `set +x` to turn it off. (Then you don't have to mess with changing all of the `$?` tests, although I would still recommend capturing returns codes to a separately named variable)

Comment: To @shellter:  The website I am connecting to is majorgeeks.com--I have "lynx"'ed it many times before.  However, you bring up a good point--I'll try a couple other websites, see if that does anything.

Comment: While I agree about wget (and check out curl too), the version of lynx that I've used in the past had a cmd-line option that saving allowed directly saving the output of a URL to a file. Also, just noticed your simplified example, and recommend that you always surrond just about all of your variables when with dbl-quotes, ie. `lynx "$line"`. Spaces in variable values can really mess things up. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have answered this question a long time ago. I got the program working, [it's now on Github!](https://github.com/spideyclick/Lynx-Program-Downloader)

Anyway, I simply had to wrap the loop inside a function. Something like this:

```
progdownload () {
  printlog "attmpting download from ${URL}"
  if echo "${URL}" | grep -q "http://www.majorgeeks.com/" ; then
lynx -cmd_script="${WORKINGDIR}/support/mgcmd.txt" --accept-all-cookies ${URL}
  else wget ${URL}
  fi
  }
URL="something.com"
progdownload
```

Answer (score 2):

Lynx is not designed to use in scripts because it locks the terminal. Lynx is an interactive console browser.

If you want to access URLs in a script use `wget`, for example:

```
wget http://www.google.com/
```

For exit codes see: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

to parse the html-content use:

```
VAR=`wget -qO- http://www.google.com/`
echo $VAR
```

Comment: I have used lynx in other scripts just fine--in fact, I repeated it a few dozen times without any hiccup.  However, those scripts did not use any while-do-done loops or anything--they were separate commands, one for each and every site.  That is one of the reasons I am making this script, in the hopes of making the other much more simple.

Comment: Also, as far as wget goes, that is what I already use primarily.  I am only using lynx to download files that need to go through a site and generate a unique download link--a lot of the programs have to be downloaded from an external download site like majorgeeks, and they won't let a wget through--as far as I know.  It would have to be able to hit a series of links or something...

Comment: When downloading a link with wget you can just parse the generated link, and wget this link again If you don't want to use wget you can also use cURL, it's available for nearly every unix-like os (see http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).

Comment: Will have to take a look at cURL, just might be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way which may fulfilled your requirement to run lynx command in loop with substitution of different url link.

Use

```
echo `lynx $line`
```

(Echo the lynx $line in single quote('))
instead of `lynx $line`. You may refer below:

**your code**

```
!#/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
echo $line
lynx $line
echo "lynx done"
done < "ref/url" 
read "lynx"

$SHELL
```

**try on below**

```
!#/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
echo $line
echo `lynx $line`
echo "lynx done"
done < "ref/url"
```